# Matplotlib segmentation fault when plotting large number of images

Tags: python, matplotlib, segmentation-fault

I have function which plots 3D numpy array as stack of images:

```
def plotImages( 
    prefix, F, slices,
    extent=None, zs = None, figsize=default_figsize, 
    cmap=default_cmap, interpolation=default_interpolation, vmin=None, vmax=None, cbar=False, 
    ):
    for ii,i in enumerate(slices):
        print " plotting ", i
        plt.figure( figsize=figsize )
        plt.imshow( F[i], origin='image', interpolation=interpolation, cmap=cmap, extent=extent, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax )
        if cbar:
            plt.colorbar();
        plt.xlabel(r' Tip_x $\AA$')
        plt.ylabel(r' Tip_y $\AA$')
        if zs is None:
            plt.title( r"iz = %i" %i  )
        else:
            plt.title( r"Tip_z = %2.2f $\AA$" %zs[i]  )
        plt.savefig( prefix+'_%3.3i.png' %i, bbox_inches='tight' )
        plt.close()
```

I call this function in loop for ~20 datagrids (3D numpy arrays) each with ~50 slices => it produces `~20 x ~50 = ~1000` images.

but after few hundreds of images it crashes with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Thisproblem is pretty hard to track, since it appears randomly, and it takes long runtime ( 10 minutes ) until it crashes.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is inside matplotlib (or numpy ?), because it crashes in the middle of this loop where are only matplotlib functions.

Also I think it maybe **depends on memory usage (?)**. The more programs I have open the sooner the problem appears. Also the problem diminished (appears much later) when I started to clean memory ( call `plt.close()` and `delete F` on my datagrids ). I was thinking If it is connected with garbage collection or something like that ?

1. Do you have some idea what could be the probme ?
2. What strategy you recommend to trace it ?

---

**EDIT:** I made this very simple artificial example, which reproduce the crash

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

default_figsize = (3,3)

def plotImages( prefix, F, figsize=default_figsize ):
    slices = range( len( F ) )
    for ii,i in enumerate(slices):
        print " plotting ", i
        plt.figure( figsize=figsize )
        plt.imshow( F[i], origin='image' )
        plt.title( r"iz = %i" %i  )
        plt.savefig( prefix+'_%3.3i.png' %i, bbox_inches='tight' )
        plt.close()


nx = 500
ny = 500
nz = 100
ng = 100

for i in range( ng ):
    F = np.random.randn( nz,ny,nx )
    print "NEW GRID ", i , " : ", np.shape(F)
    plotImages( "", F )
    del F
```

The `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` appears after at grid #12 slice #54 this means after 11x100 + 54 = 1154 images plotted

output is like:

```
NEW GRID  12  :  (100, 500, 500)
 plotting  0
 plotting  1
 plotting  2
 .... # ommited lines here
 plotting  50
 plotting  51
 plotting  52
 plotting  53
 plotting  54
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```